# WTForms define one of many specific field by logic in __init__() of form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a few custom SelectFields. And I would like to use one of them according to some logic.
For example:

```
# in view
@app.route('/some/<int:a>/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def f(a):
    form = MyForm(a=a)
    return render_template('t.html', form=form)

# in forms
class MyForm(Form):
    next = HiddenField()
    static_field1 = StringField()
    static_field2 = StringField()
    static_field3 = StringField()

    # this is problem
    # if a == 1 I need specific_field = CustomSelect1(),
    # but if a == 2, I need specific_field = CustomSelect()2

    specific_field = ?
```

I guess I should use **init**() constructor in MyForm.
But I do not know how to do it correctly

Can you help me?

Thanks

UPD 0:
Maybe I can solve this problem by Meta-classes?

UPD 1:
I'm understand, exist are many ways how to do this, but what way is good practice?

Comment: What's the difference between the fields?

Comment: They included different data from db. If details: I have a form for registration some items movement. Users can move items between two kinds of places, A and B, for example. A and B - it two different sets of places from db.

Comment: Why not creating two different forms? And you would have your logic in the method f?

Comment: Jeremy D, in simple case in form I have 1 static field (value), and 2 dynamic (from_obj, to_obj). If exist two different kind of obj (see previous comments) we already have 4 combination of forms: from A to A, from A to B, from B to B, from B to A. And creating form for each, looks like not good practice. Am I right?

Comment: Does that mean that you want to populate the `select` field with different values?

Comment: dirn, correct. Maybe I need to use Meta-Class for create MyCustomSelectField for each case? Or something like Dynamic Form Composition from Docs (http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specific_problems.html)?